# How can I do this using Reduce function?

Tags: javascript, reduce

```js
var ｙ= '110001'.split("").reverse();
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  sum += (y[i] * Math.pow(2, i));
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be simplest to do

```js
console.log(Array.from('110001').reduce((prev, cur) => prev << 1 | cur));
```

`<<` is the left-bitshift operator, which here essentially multiplies by two.

`Array.from` (if available) is preferable to `split`. In this case it doesn't matter, but `split` will fail with surrogate pair characters such as , while `Array.from` will handle them correctly. This could also be written as `[...'110001']`, which ends up being the same thing.

Of course, you could also just say

```
parseInt('110001', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

check this snippet

```js
var binary = '110001'.split("").reverse();

var sum = binary.reduce(function(previous, current, index) {
  previous = previous + (current * Math.pow(2, index));
  return previous;
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Hope it helps