# Get the difference of arrays in ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have two arrays:

```
const allLanguages = [ 'ES', 'EN', 'DE' ]
const usedLanguages = [ { id: 1, lang: 'EN' } ]
```

What's the quickest way to produce a new array which is the difference between these two? In old school JavaScript, you'd have to do a for loop inside another for loop, I think...

Eg:

```
const availableLanguages = [ 'ES', 'DE' ]
```

Comment: Or fastest run-time performance? If that is really your goal--in other words, this code is executed millions of times and is mission-critical to your app--then you **are** better off writing some `for` loops.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `find()` to return filtered array.

```js
const allLanguages = [ 'ES', 'EN', 'DE' ]
const usedLanguages = [ { id: 1, lang: 'EN' } ]

var result = allLanguages.filter(e => !usedLanguages.find(a => e == a.lang));
console.log(result)
```

You could also `map()` second array and then use `includes()` to filter out duplicates.

```js
const allLanguages = [ 'ES', 'EN', 'DE' ]
const usedLanguages = [ { id: 1, lang: 'EN' } ].map(e => e.lang);

var result = allLanguages.filter(e => !usedLanguages.includes(e));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You may want to use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.find()`, so that there's no foolery with falsiness.

Comment: `some` short circuits in the exact same way as `find`

Comment: @4castle Yea my mistake, their difference is in output not in performance.

Comment: @4castle What kind of foolery are you referring to? Falsiness of what?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm referring to the falsiness of the value returned by `find`. In this case an object would never be falsy, but in general the type coersion is unnecessary and open to bugs if the circumstances were different.

Comment: Unfortunately, although using "includes" makes the solution a lot prettier than using "some", the function "includes" isn't supported at all in Internet Explorer...

Comment: @Shai But the question specifically requested ES6!

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, you are correct. I didn't notice it, sorry. Still, I think mentioning it is still relevant :p

Comment: @Shai Then you need to also mention that arrow functions are not supported.

Comment: @torazaburo Again, you are completely right and arrow functions aren't supported either in IE.

Comment: @shai I do not agree with term "unfortunately" with regard to incompatibilities of Internet Explorer. It is not compatible with standards by mere design and intention

Comment: @maoizm I meant that if the OP wants to target IE as well, he won't be able to use `includes` and also arrow functions, which is unfortunate.

Comment: although this post is 3 years old, here is my solution `var result = allLanguages.filter(e => usedLanguages.find(a => e == a.lang).length === 0)`;
with the length check, the always truthiness is avoided...

Answer (score 15):

#### Set-based approach

Inspired by @Ori Drori's excellent answer, here is a pure set-based solution.

```
const all = new Set(allLanguages);
const used = new Set(usedLanguages.map(({lang}) => lang));

const availableLanguages = setDifference(all, used);
```

where

```
const setDifference = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => !b.has(x)));
```

`availableLanguages` will be a set, so to work with it as an array you'll need to do `Array.from` or `[...map]` on it.

If one wanted to get all functional, then

```
const not = fn => x => !fn(x);
const isIn = set => x => set.has(x);
```

Now write

```
const setDifference = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(not(isIn(b))));
```

which some might consider more semantic or readable.

However, these solutions are somewhat unsatisfying and could be suboptimal. Even though `Set#has` is `O(1)`, compared to `O(n)` for `find` or `some`, the overall performance is still `O(n)`, since we have to iterate through all the elements of `a`. It would be better to delete the elements from `b` from `a`, as was suggested in another answer. This would be

```
const setDifference = (a, b) => {
  const result = new Set(a);
  b.forEach(x => result.delete(x));
  return result;
}
```

We can't use `reduce` since that is not available on sets, and we don't want to have to convert the set into an array to use it. But we can use `forEach`, which is available on sets. This alternative would be preferable if `a` is larger and `b` is smaller.

Most likely some future version of JS will have this built-in, allowing you to just say

```
const availableLanguages = all.difference(used)
```

#### Generator-based approach

Finally, if we are interested in exploring more ES6 features, we could write this as a generator which generates non-duplicate values, as in

```
function* difference(array, excludes) {
  for (let x of array) 
    if (!excludes.includes(x)) yield x;
}
```

Now we can write

```
console.log([...difference(allLanguages, usedLanguages)]);
```

This solution might be recommended if there was a long list of languages, perhaps coming in one by one, and you wanted to get a stream of the non-used ones.

#### Using a dictionary

If one wanted `O(1)` lookup into the list of exclusions without using sets, the classic approach is to pre-calculate a dictionary:

```
const dict = Object.assign({}, 
    ...usedLanguages.map(({lang}) => ({[lang]: true})));

const availableLanguages = allLanguages.filter(lang => lang in dict);
```

If that way of computing the dictionary is too arcane for you, then some people use `reduce`:

```
const dict = usedLanguages.reduce((obj, {lang}) => {
  obj[lang] = true;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Nina likes to write this using the comma operator as

```
const dict = usedLanguages.reduce((obj, {lang}) => (obj[lang] = true, obj), {});
```

which saves some curly braces.

Or, since JS still has `for` loops :-):

```
const dict = {};
for (x of usedLanguages) {
  dict[x.lang] = true;
}
```

Hey, you're the one who said you want to use ES6.

Comment: I feel that my education is complete :) Loved the arcane way to create a dictionary.

Comment: The dictionary approach could be improved by using `Object.create(null)` for the empty object, so that things from `Object.prototype` don't give false positives.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code:

```
availableLanguages = allLanguages.filter((lang1) => !usedLanguages.some((lang2) => lang2.lang === lang1))
```

The `some` function is a lesser known relative to `find` that is better suited for cases where you want to check if a condition is met by at least one element in the array.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate the `usedLanguages` using `Array#reduce`, with `new Set(allLanguages)` as the start value. Delete the language from `used` Set on every iteration. Spread the result into array. Complexity is O(n + m), where n is the length of the `usedLanguages` array, and m the length of `allLanguages`:

```js
const allLanguages = [ 'ES', 'EN', 'DE' ];
const usedLanguages = [{ id: 1, lang: 'EN' }];

const result = [...usedLanguages.reduce((r, { lang }) => {
  r.delete(lang);
  return r;
}, new Set(allLanguages))];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My lot in life. I'm pooling all my meager ES6 knowledge to provide an answer, and the only response is from a loops guy :)

Comment: You've used the spread operator, sets, arrow functions, and destructuring, but you've left out promises, proxies, classes, and generators. :-)

Comment: As I've said "my meager ES6 knowledge". However, I've decided to repent! No more! I will use loops! I will learn from the master. Imagine my shock and dismay when I've found this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40944997/5157454