# Optimising ES6 intersection of Arrays function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following Arrays:

```
this.originalSelectedRows = [1,2,3,4,5];
this.selectedRows = [3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

I want to know the following:

How many numbers are in `this.originalSelectedRows`, but not in `this.selectedRows`

Which in this case would be 2:

1 and 2

and how many numbers are in `this.selectedRows`, but not `this.originalSelectedRows`

Which in this case would be 3:

6, 7 and 8

I have the following, which works fine:

```
    let isOnListCount = 0;
    let isNotOnListCount = 0

    this.selectedRows.map((row) => {
      const isSelected = this.originalSelectedRows.filter(x => x === row);
        if(isSelected.length > 0)
          isOnListCount++;
        else
          isNotOnListCount++;
    });
```

But I want to know if this can be achieved in a neater fashion usng some of ES6's new features, or original JS

Comment: Can you assume they are sorted in general?

Comment: You are looking for the **difference** between the two arrays. Google for that.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998880/get-the-different-of-arrays-in-es6

Comment: This question has an answer with a lot of ideas, including using ES6 generators. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998880/get-the-different-of-arrays-in-es6/41001435#41001435

Comment: If the arrays are always sorted, replace the `.includes` in the below answers with a binary search.

Comment: why does your code works fine, if you get as result 3 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [**Array#includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function to check if the element exists in the second array or not

```js
const originalSelectedRows = [1,2,3,4,5];
const selectedRows = [3,4,5,6,7,8];

let isOnListCount = 0;
let isNotOnListCount = 0;

selectedRows.forEach(row => 
 originalSelectedRows.includes(row) ? isOnListCount++ : isNotOnListCount++
);

console.log(isOnListCount);
console.log(isNotOnListCount);
```

Comment: @Alex You've accepted an answer which gives an answer different from that you yourself said was correct, which was a `2` for the first case.

Comment: You are right. I am going to remove this answer. I didn't notice that my result is wrong. Remove the acceptance, to let me remove this

Comment: Why don't you just fix the answer, instead of deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

You could take the length as counter and reduce the value with common items.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    count1 = array1.length,
    count2 = array2.length;
    
array1.forEach(function (a) {
    if (array2.includes(a)) {
        count1--;
        count2--;
    }
});
console.log(count1, count2);
```

Comment: Readability is more important than short fancy code. You always have a way of making the most simple logic completely incomprehensible to new programmers.

Comment: Specifically `&& (count1--, count2--)` is something new users will not recognize. `&&` as shortcut `if` and the `( , )` aren't common structures that they will recognize.

Comment: @NinaScholz I know how much you wanted to use `reduce`, and write more obscure code. Here you go: `const common = arr.reduce((result, elt) => result + array2.includes(elt));`. Note the clever way we add a boolean. Now the answers are simply `array1.length - common` and `array2.length - common`.

Comment: @torazaburo, you know (i hope so), that i am able to write that in reduce style, but it is not necessary in this case (for saving a single line of code).

Answer (score 1):

Sets will do a great job here :)

```
let set1 = new Set(this.originalSelectedRows)
let set2 = new Set(this.selectedRows)
let difference = new Set([...set1].filter(n => !set2.has(n)))
```

They are also relatively fast as well, but not as fast as a specially crafted solution :P

I am assuming that all of your items are unique though :)

Comment: I love your smilies--do they mean there is some kind of joke in there that I missed? :-)

Comment: I really do need to ease up on the smiles! Dang!

Answer (score 1):

I'd convert one array into a set and than filter the other array for items which aren't in the set.

```js
const
  valuesA = [1,2,3,4,5],
  valuesB = [3,4,5,6,7,8];
  
function getUniqueValues(sourceArray, testArray) {
  const 
    set = new Set(testArray);
    
  return sourceArray.filter(value => !set.has(value));
}

console.log(`Values in A and not in B: ${getUniqueValues(valuesA, valuesB)}`);
console.log(`Values in B and not in A: ${getUniqueValues(valuesB, valuesA)}`);
```